# When creating an init.d demon, what is the .service file?

Tags: systemd, raspberry-pi, init.d

I am trying to create a service that will eventually run at start, however I am getting stuck just trying to get the service to run using:

```
sudo service fortech_bluetooth_server start
```

Whenever I run this command the error that I receive is:

```
Failed to start fortech_bluetooth_server.service: Unit fortech_bluetooth_server.service failed to load: No such file or directory.
```

However, when I run the init.d script directly it works perfectly. Do I need to make another file to go with the init.d script? Modify a file?

Also, any help with the jargon would be appreciated. I'm new to working with daemons.

Comment: You have a OS which is transitioning from sysV to systemd, this behavior is because the `service * [start|stop|...]` and init.d scripts are deprecated and replaced with systemd which uses unit files for all its configuration and services, you can read about it here: https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/
If you need more help with your service file post the contents of the script in init.d and I can help you with your unit file